# How to share/port a dashboard in QlikView over non-web content?

Tags: business-intelligence, dashboard, qlikview

Background:

1. ETL on source data from Excel, Access, Sql Server '8, .txt files.
2. Data Cloud is created
3. Dashboard is in progress

I have searched online because I remember seeing a marketting demo video by QlikView that it's possible to share the dashboard among other users. Not just a snapshot image or pdf. The real dashboard as a working file.

If client pcs receive a link to connect to the same data cloud via web - that's easy.
But what I want to know, is it possible to package and "port" the entire working file with underlying data to another person? (I am not asking for *zipping*!)

Comment: You can share objects that users have created, but you cannot share a whole Dashboard and the objects on it. Only one object a time sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on if you've purchased a license for Qlikview, there are several ways to approach this... Best case scenario for you is if you and the client you want to send the `.qvw` to both have Named licenses, you can just send them the file and they'll be able to open it in their licensed Personal Edition. I'm imagining this is not the case since you mentioned they are clients and not colleagues within your organization.

You need to know that **if the client or you do not own licenses, you will not be able to share a working version of your dashboard with them**.

The common implementation would be purchasing Qlikview Server Software and then deploying a Qlikview server in the cloud that would handle incoming web requests and provide clients with an access point from which to access your dashboards (and underlying data). This solution requires you (or your company) to have purchased a set of licenses from Qlik as well as Server software.

You can review Qlik's license structure [here](https://expertqv.com/qlikview-licenses/#toggle-id-1). You may also want to review their [End User License Agreement](http://prod.qlik.com/us/info/software-ula) to make sure their model works for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ah - VIP : I have made a typo. I was just talking in terms of client's perspective. But infact I just want to know if two people without any remote connection want to share dashboard over their email. Can I send a *package* sort of a configuration file that can be opened in other person's pc and view the dashboard - do some changes and send it back to me? If it's web I understand two people can access the dashboard and view it at the same time and if one person does changes - it will be immediately available to the other audience upon a refreshing-click.